# cakephp reverse routing conflicts with pagination logic

Tags: cakephp, routes, pagination

I've a new question :)
I'll briefly explain what I'm trying to achieve. Right now I have an url that looks like this.

```
/products/index/brand:figleaves
```

I want this to look like this

```
/brand/figleaves
```

By writing the following route rule I get what I want.

```
Router::connect('/brand/:brand/*', array('controller' => 'products', 'action' => 'index'));
```

Everything goes fine, but then I discovered the pagination logic has been destructed.
If I click on 'next page' I get redirected to the url `/products/index/page:2`.

1. it doesn't pass the brand parameter
2. it redirects back to the products_controller and not to the url I defined in the route rule.

In fact I'd need this as url `/brand/figleaves/page:2`.

Strange thing is if I browse to `/products/index/brand:figleaves` and click on Next, then I get redirected to `/brand/figleaves/page:2`. How can this be explained?

I'd appreciate some help with this :)

Kind Regards,
Laurent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For those interested in how I solved this.

I just defined some options in the paginator in my view and passed the value explicitly, like this.

```
    $this->Paginator->options(array
            ('url'=> array(
                'controller' => 'products', 
                'action' => 'index',
                'brand'=>$this->params['brand']
   )));
```

That does the job :)